# Merge Data with InDesign and Loop through a Subset of Data

Tags: xml, csv, adobe-indesign

I have a spreadsheet I am using Data Merge to pull into my InDesign publication. One of the fields contains multiple rows of data, but is only separated by HTML tags... UL list actually. I am not too experienced with InDesign btw...

Is there a way to loop through this small set of data found in the csv or xml file to insert into one field in my .indd?

My .indd file looks like:

```
<<Title>><<Description>>
<<Items>>
```

<> contains this extra data (ul list). I would like to see it in my output in a formatted way I control...

Is there something like:

```
<<Items[arrayofdata]>>???\
```

or

```
<<Items.datafield>>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot achieve that. Either you convert your html list into flat columns but it will also require matching datamerge tags; or you can flatten teh list as regular paragraphs in a record column but it will probably cause issues in the datamerge process (as carriage returns in the field will be understood as a new line record.
An alternative is not using a carriage return in your field but some dummy string like ##CR## that you will later Find/replace within InDesign.

Answer (score 0):

if `<<Items[arrayofdata]>>` is going to reside inside a single text block, you could in your csv create your own data separator. Below I use '&&' to show what I mean:

```
Title,Description,Items
My things,The things I have in my collection,item1&&item2&&item3&&item4
```

Once you've pulled in the data merge in inDesign you simply do a Edit=>Find/Change where find is && and replace it with whatever structure you need. (inDesign even offers a little help with the @ to build a series of characters and not just one)